# Question on eigenvalue properties

Tags: matrices

If $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of matrix $A$ and $B=S^{-1} A S$ show that $\lambda$ is also eigenvalue of matrix $B$. Also show that if matrix $A^{2015}$ is a zero matrix then its only eigenvalue is $0$.

The first problem I tackled like this. if $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of $B$ it solves this equation.
\begin{align*}
B&=S^{-1} A S\;\;\;|\cdot x\\
Bx&=(S^{-1} A S) x\;\;\;\text{where }(S^{-1} A S)=\lambda
\end{align*}
So this means that $\lambda=S^{-1} A S$ and it should solve:
\begin{align*}
Ax&=(S^{-1} A S)x\\
A&=S^{-1}AS=B
\end{align*}
And shouldn't this hold because now while writing that I was thinking that for all matrises $X$ if you multiply it first with matrix $S$ and then with $S^{-1}$ should it be $X$ so does this hold for all matrises?:

$$B=S^{-1}AS=A$$

Isn't the second question very trivial because $A^{2015}=\mathbf{0}$
\begin{align*}
A^{2015}x&=\lambda x \\
\mathbf{0}x &= \lambda x \\
\mathbf{0} &= \lambda x\;\;\text{where } x\neq\mathbf{0} \text{ thus}\\
\lambda &= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: In the second part you're only showing that $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A^{2015}$ - that doesn't prove anything about the eigenvalues of $A$ itself. And I don't quite understand what you're saying in the first part - what do you mean for example by $S^{-1}AS=\lambda$? On the left side of the equation sign is a matrix, and on the right side a number, so it's not even sensible as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar matrices have same eigenvalues.
$$B=S^{-1}AS$$
$f_B(\lambda)=\text{det}(B-\lambda I)=\text{det}(S^{-1}AS-\lambda I)=\text{det}(S^{-1}(A-\lambda I)S)=\text{det}(A-\lambda I)=f_A(\lambda)$

**Hint:**

$A^{2015}=0$ implies $A$ is nilpotent.  Can you get the characteristics polynomial from this?

> nilpotent matrices has eigenvalue $0$

Comment: I would think that in this case the point of the exercise is exactly to show that nilpotent matrices can only have $0$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: That first part makes perfect sense now... For the second: \begin{align}\operatorname{det}\left( \begin{bmatrix}
    -\lambda & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
   0 & -\lambda & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & -\lambda
\end{bmatrix} \right) &= 0\\
(-\lambda)^n \operatorname{det}(\mathbf{I}) &= 0\\
\lambda &= 0\end{align}
Does this seems correct?

Comment: You can just consider the characteristic polynomial as $\lambda^{2015}=0$. Indeed an $n\times n$ nilpotent matrix has characteristic polynomial $x^n=0$

Comment: How so @Quintic ? Does my brute force tactic also hold? I think it does...

Comment: Your's seems to be fine. You know Cayley hamilton theorem right? It follows from just that.

Comment: @Quintic I do not :/. By the way in the proof you simplify $\text{det}(S^{-1}(A-\lambda I)S)=\text{det}(A-\lambda I)$. Doesn't this mean that for all matrises $A$ and $S \to$  $S^{-1} A S = A$ and thus the we could show that $B=A$ from the beginning?

Comment: $\det(S^{-1}(A-\lambda I)S)=\det(S)\det(A-\lambda I)\det(S)^{-1}$ since the determinant of a product is the product of determinants. $\det X=\det Y$ does not mean $X=Y$.

Comment: That's genius!! Thanks @MattDickau

Comment: Just one more question @MattDickau: You form this equality $S^{-1}AS-\lambda I = S^{-1}(A-\lambda I)S$. Are you allowed to to multiply those matrises which ever way you want into the brackets? because it seems it goes like $S^{-1}(A-\lambda I)S = S^{-1}A S - S S^{-1} \lambda I$ ?

Comment: Because $IX=X=XI$ for any matrix $X$, and $S^{-1}S=I$, we can write $I=S^{-1}IS$. Then the equality in question follows from distributivity. So it only works because $I$ is the identity matrix and commutes with every matrix; $S^{-1}AS-\lambda B \ne S^{-1}(A-\lambda B)S$ in general.

Answer (score 0):

To show that if $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $B=S^{-1}AS$ does as well, let $x$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with the given eigenvalue, and let $y=S^{-1}x$.
$$By=(S^{-1}AS)(S^{-1}x)=S^{-1}Ax=S^{-1}(\lambda x)=\lambda S^{-1}x=\lambda y$$
Hence, $y$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$; therefore $B$ has all the same eigenvalues as $A$ (though with different eigenvectors).

To show that if $A^n=0$ for some $n$ (that is, $A$ is nilpotent) then the only eigenvalue of $A$ is zero, consider how the eigenvalues of $A^n$ relate to those of $A$. If $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$ with eigenvector $x$, then:
$$Ax=\lambda x$$
$$A^2x=A(Ax)=A(\lambda x)=\lambda Ax=\lambda^2x$$
$$A^3x=A(A^2x)=\lambda^3x$$
and so on. So the eigenvalues of $A^n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ raised to the $n$-th power. If $A^n$ is the zero matrix, then its only eigenvalue is zero as you have shown; but this means that the only eigenvalue of $A$ is the $n$-th root of zero - which is just zero itself.

Comment: Nice alternative method! I think my method: \begin{align}\operatorname{det}\left( \begin{bmatrix}     -\lambda & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\    0 & -\lambda & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\     0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & -\lambda \end{bmatrix} \right) &= 0\\ (-\lambda)^n \operatorname{det}(\mathbf{I}) &= 0\\ \lambda &= 0\end{align}
works as well.

Comment: I think that only shows that the eigenvalues of the zero matrix are all zero; you still need to relate that back to the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: good point! Yours is pretty elegant :)